# Bar Chart not working

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

My code creates a bar chart, but the bars are quite thin and far apart. Also, I want to add the labels ("Bitcoin" and "VISA" under each bar respectively, but this isn't working for me either...

Please could someone help with this? Thank you very much in advance for your help.
[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{cfets.csv}
column1 column2
8  1005
14 169
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
           ybar,
            bar width=.4cm,
            enlarge x limits={abs=.4cm},
            xtick=data,
            x tick label style={color=white},
            nodes near coords,
            nodes near coords align={vertical},
            ymin=0,ymax=1200,
            ylabel={Energy consumption in kilowatt-hours},
        ]
        \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y=column2] {cfets.csv}; 

      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...Your tag works well, hope the problem may lies in old packages, update your `TeX` setup and then check...

Comment: Thanks! I'm running it in Overleaf... Could that be the problem?

Comment: Hope so...but not sure, as I don't have enough experience in `Overleaf`

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE! You can use, for instance, `x=1.1cm` in the `axis` options to determine the length of the *x* vector. This will make the bars closer to each other here, and reduce the plot width (in your code, `pgfplots` determines *x* and *y* units in order to obtain a plot that is `\axisdefaultwidth` wide and `\axisdefaultheight` high, the defaults for these being respectively 240 and 207 points, which gives the customary rectangular box for plots made with `pgfplots`).

For your Bitcoin and VISA labels, my suggestion would be to include them in your data, for instance like this:

```latex
column1  column2
Bitcoin  1005
VISA     169
```

and use `symbolic x coords={Bitcoin,VISA}` in conjunction with `\addplot table[x=column1, y=column2] {cfets.csv};`.

I also used `small` in the `axis` options so as to reduce the font size—the bars are not that wide and closer now; we don't want the *x* labels to touch each other. I would recommend setting a recent `pgfplots` compatibility level, as in `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}`.

Finally, please note that [the `filecontents` package is obsolete with recent LaTeX](https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews30.pdf). As a consequence, there is no need for `\usepackage{filecontents}` anymore.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{cfets.csv}
column1  column2
Bitcoin  1005
VISA     169
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    small,
    ybar,
    x=1.1cm, bar width=.6cm,
    enlarge x limits={abs=.4cm},
    symbolic x coords={Bitcoin,VISA},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={vertical},
    ymin=0, ymax=1200,
    ylabel={Energy consumption in kilowatt-hours},
    ]
    \addplot table[x=column1, y=column2] {cfets.csv};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]